# Read lines from GitHub user content file

Tags: python, python-2.7, proxy, python-requests

I'm trying to read a text file (proxies list) from GitHub user content. Code shall return a random line, but it doesn't work as expected.

My code:

```
res = reqs.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/clarketm/proxy-list/master/proxy-list-raw.txt', headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})
proxies = []
for lines in res.text:
    proxies = ''.join(lines)
    print proxies
return proxies
```

Here is what I get:

```
.
2
1
:
8
0
8
0


1
9
2
.
1
6
2
.
6
2
.
1
9
7
:
5
9
2
4
6
```

Here is what is expected:

```
178.217.106.245:8080
186.192.98.250:8080
```

If random line can be returned this would be even better.

Comment: Changed title to follow the content, improved formatting of the post, including code parts and text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Result is a string, iterating over a string iterates over letters, not lines.
You'll have to split the string by newlines and iterate over that:

```py
for lines in res.text.split('\n'):
   ...
```